# How does bitwise operator work the avr atmega register?

Tags: c, uart, atmega

In the below code image bitwise left shift operator is used with the register for uart initialization,How does that left shift operator (1(left shift)RXEN),(1(left shift)) work when register bit(RXEN,TXEN) is not initialised

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R3KE.png)

Here is the link for Register description and code
https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/UART_Programming_with_Atmega128

Comment: Those values are typically macros contained in device-specific header files. They expand to the index of the bits used.

Comment: Please do not post code as images. It didn't appear in your question because it wasn't formatted as code.

Comment: when i use << operator contents after that are not appearing

Comment: See this page for information on how to format questions: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: Do not post code as image.

Comment: Please select your code and mark it as code; it's currently illegible.

Answer (score 0):

there are definitions  of the bit numbers of the corresponding  bits in the hardware registers. it is easier for humans to remember names not numbers

Comment: U mean 1 << D4 or 1<< 4and 1<< D3 or 1<<3 is what 1<< Rxen and 1<<txen means

Comment: From now on I will call you 458654.

Comment: What is that 458654, I dint get what ur telling,I want the answer

Comment: @P__J__ I understood now